# Angular2 'this' is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I have a code that looks like this:

```
export class CRListComponent extends ListComponent<CR> implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private crService: CRService) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.getCount(new Object(), this.crService.getCount);
    }
```

The ListComponent code is this

```
@Component({})
export abstract class ListComponent<T extends Listable> {

    protected getCount(event: any, countFunction: Function){
        let filters = this.parseFilters(event.filters);
        countFunction(filters)
            .subscribe(
                count => {
                    this.totalItems = count;
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

And the appropriate service code fragment from CRService is this:

```
getCount(filters) {
    var queryParams = JSON.stringify(
        {
            c : 'true',
            q : filters
        }
    );

    return this.createQuery(queryParams)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now when my `ngOnInit()` runs, I get an error:

> angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'createQuery' of undefined in [null]
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'createQuery' of undefined

So basically, the `this` in the `return this.createQuery(queryParams)` statement will be null. Does anybody have an idea how is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think `this.createQuery` exists?

Comment: is it "normal" that your 2 classes are missing a closing bracket ?

Comment: I just omitted the unnecessary parts, the code is syntactically correct otherwise. :) The problem is not with `.createQuery`, it's with `this` itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is located here:

```
gOnInit():any {
    this.getCount(new Object(), this.crService.getCount); // <----
}
```

Since you reference a function outside an object. You could use the `bind` method on it:

```
this.getCount(new Object(), this.crService.getCount.bind(this.crService));
```

or wrap it into an arrow function:

```
this.getCount(new Object(), (filters) => {
  return this.crService.getCount(filters));
});
```

The second approach would be the preferred one since it allows to keep types. See this page for more details:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! Is there a way I can do this in HTML template bindings? I mean, I have the following code:
`(onLazyLoad)="loadItems($event, this.crService.getCRs)"`

Can I also transform this into something like this?
`(onLazyLoad)="loadItems($event, (page, n, sortField, sortOrder, filters) => { return this.crService.getCRs(page, n, sortField, sortOrder, filters)})"`

Comment: Great! You don't need to use the `this` keyword in templates. That said, I would use an intermediate level. I mean: using the this.crService.getCRs within the `loadItems` method...

Comment: Good, I also ended up with this solution. This seems also much cleaner than embedding such ugly code in my HTML templates. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error I yanked all the innards out of my function causing the error and threw it in another function then the error went away.

example:

I had this function with some code in it

```
this.globalListenFunc = renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
  // bunch of code to evaluate click event
  // this is the code that had the "this" undefined error
});
```

I pulled the code out and put it in an external public function, here's the finished code:

```
this.globalListenFunc = renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
  this.evaluateClick(event);
});

evaluateClick(evt: MouseEvent){
    // all the code I yanked out from above
}
```